# das Gehalt vs. der Gehalt

Tags: gender

In the sense "salary; wage; stipend", the word *Gehalt* can be either masculine or neuter. [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=gehalt) writes this as

> das/[österr. auch] der Gehalt

What is the difference between the word in these genders? Do they carry different connotations? Could I use the neutral form in Austria and the masculine in Germany?

Comment: I never heared "der Gehalt", it sounds kind of weird to me.

Comment: Only in the other meaning of "concentration"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like you said, *Das Gehalt* means *the salary*. *Der Gehalt* means *salary* in Austria, and it means *the content* (in a mixture). <sup>([wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gehalt), [duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gehalt_Lohn_Entgelt))</sup>

> Das Gehalt ist Tarifgebunden
>
> Der Fettgehalt der Milch is 3,8 %.

The masculine form just doesn't work, if you're talking about Salary, in Germany. Austria uses both forms, but drifts towards using the neutral form.

- Leaving aside whether they're understood properly: they don't carry different connotations.

Switzerland, southern Germany, and - to a lesser extend - Austria also use *[Salär](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sal%C3%A4r)*.

Comment: "The neutral form just doesn't work, if you're talking about Salary, in Germany."  **neutral**?

Comment: I know Austrians speaking of **Salär** instead of **Gehalt**.

Comment: *Salär* kommt wohl von französisch *salaire*.

Comment: "Salär" in southern Germany? Never heard of it in Bavaria. Here its called "Lohn, Gehalt"

Answer (score 9):

der Gehalt = content, proportion, percentage, concentration

das Gehalt = salary, pay, remuneration

As a German, I'm not informed about the above mentioned Austrian variants, but in Germany, "der Gehalt" has nothing to do with getting paid for work.

Comment: That's why I clarified that I meant the sense "salary; wage; stipend". Good to know that a German has never heard the masculine form.

Answer (score 3):

There is no semantic difference.

If you're primarily communicating with people in Germany I recommend using the neutrum version "das Gehalt".

In Austria both forms are common. I'm pretty sure that the neutrum form is the predominant gender too.